# Powershell Script throwing error when I call a function

Tags: powershell

I am getting the below error when i call the method in PowerShell. Any help would be thankful very much.

**Error:**

> Error in
>   The term 'Test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file
>   , or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included
>   , verify that the path is correct and try again.

**Code**

```
Try
{   
    Test
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Error in" 
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
}


function Test()
{
  Write-Host "Test Method Called"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your call to `Test` fails is that PowerShell scripts are not pre-compiled, but evaluated from top to bottom.

Since the `Test` function is only declared at the end of your script, it does not "exist" when the `Try-Catch` block is executed.

Simply swap the order:

```
function Test()
{
  Write-Host "Test Method Called"
}

Try
{   
    Test
}
Catch
{
    $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message
    Write-Host "Error in" 
    Write-Host $ErrorMessage
}
```

Comment: Hi Jessen, Please see my updated "Error" part in the description. I am using "." only to call the script.